# problem with event loops, gui qt5, and ipywidgets in a jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, ipywidgets

I am trying to integrate interactive ipywidgets with a loop in my code that also performs other tasks (in this case, acquiring data from some hardware attached from the computer and updating live plots).

In the past, I could do this by using `IPython.kernel.do_one_iteration()` in my `while` loop: this would trigger a sync of the ipywidget changes and I would be able to retrieve them from the python widget objects. A minimal example is here:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from time import sleep
import IPython

do_one_iteration = IPython.get_ipython().kernel.do_one_iteration

w = widgets.ToggleButton()
display(w)

i=0
while True:
    do_one_iteration()
    print(i, w.value, end="\r")
    w.decription = str(i)
    sleep(0.5)
    i+=1
```

Here, the for loop prints out the ticker integer along with the state of the widget. (In the real code, I would also acquire data, update plots, and change plot / acquisition settings dependent on the interaction with the user via the widgets.)

With ipykernel 5.3.2 and ipython 7.16.1, this worked fine: if the widget changed, calling `do_one_iteration()` synced the widget states to the kernel and I could retrieve it from my `while` loop.

After an upgrade (to 6.4.1 and 7.29.0), this no longer works. It seems that `do_one_iteration()` is now a coroutine: I get a warning `coroutine 'Kernel.do_one_iteration' was never awaited` if I use the above code.

With some help of a friend, we found a way to do this with threading an asyncio:

```
%gui asyncio
import asyncio
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.ToggleButton()
display(button)
text = widgets.Text()
display(text)
text.value= str(button.value)

stop_button = widgets.ToggleButton()
stop_button.description = "Stop"
display(stop_button)

async def f():   
    i=0
    while True:
        i += 1
        text.value = str(i) + " " + str(button.value)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        if stop_button.value == True:
            return

asyncio.create_task(f());
```

And this works (also adding a stop button, and changing to text output widget instead of printing). But to throw a spanner in the works, I need to use a library that itself uses a QT gui event loop. Some more puzzling suggests that this should be the code to make this work:

```
%gui qt5
import asyncio
import ipywidgets as widgets
import qasync

button = widgets.ToggleButton()
display(button)
text = widgets.Text()
display(text)
text.value= str(button.value)

stop_button = widgets.ToggleButton()
stop_button.description = "Stop"
display(stop_button)

async def f(): 
    while True:
        i += 1
        text.value = str(i) + " " + str(button.value)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        if stop_button.value == True:
            return

from qtpy import QtWidgets
APP = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()

loop = qasync.QEventLoop(APP)
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
asyncio.create_task(f());
```

But with this code, the updates do not propagate, and I get the following error on the terminal running my notebook server:

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gsteele/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 457, in dispatch_queue
    await self.process_one()
  File "/Users/gsteele/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 440, in process_one
    t, dispatch, args = await self.msg_queue.get()
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-2' 
coro=<Kernel.dispatch_queue() running at 
/Users/gsteele/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py:457> 
cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /Users/gsteele/anaconda3/envs/myenv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]> 
got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

It seems that somehow my ipywidgets events are propagating to the wrong event loop.

And now my question is: does anybody know what is going on here?

It's hard for me to identify if this is a "bug", and if so, in which software package do things go wrong? ipykernel? Or tornado? Or ipywidgets? Or asyncio? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Any thoughts highly welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have been frustrated by GUI (such as ipywidgets, etc.) events not being triggered in time with Jupyter notebooks and the solutions seem to be hard for beginners; but I do have a point to make here.

I didn't test all solutions above, but at least the second code block (the one with asyncio.create_task(f());) doesn't work, although the OP says it does, you can add additional Python statements at the bottom and you will see the UI events are not processed until those statements complete. It seems tne asyncio solutions don't work well with Jupyter.

One thing I see that works is jupyter_ui_poll and that is as simple as the following, please let me know if you have further findouts, thanks in advance.

```
from jupyter_ui_poll import ui_events

......................................

with ui_events() as ui_poll:
    ui_poll(10) # poll queued UI events including button
```

Comment: Thanks Dino, awesome! My other solution broke after an upgrade, but this solves it in a less-hackey-way!

Answer (score 0):

Found at least a partial solution: using the `nest_asyncio` package allows me to now use `do_one_iteration()`, just by adding the following to the first code block:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

and then using `await do_one_iteration()` instead of calling it directly.

(see https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/825)

For my purposes, this solves my issue since I don't need asynchronous interaction with my GUI. The problem of the `%gui qt5` interaction with the event loop in the asynchronous versions of the code is still a mystery though...